# Article review SE site

Tags: discussion, review, area-51, article

I've looked around on the [Sites overview](https://stackexchange.com/sites) of Stack Exchange and noticed there is a site for code review, but none for (blog) article review. I myself always look for a couple of proofreaders for my articles, and I think I'm not alone. An easy way to find proofreaders, or a platform to use with your current proofreaders to get feedback in an easy format, would be greatly appreciated by me, and I think others as well.

I did find the [Writing Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) on the sites overview, but its description does not seem to closely relate to what I'm looking for in particular. On Area 51, there's the [Writer's Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers), which seems to relate more to what I'm looking for, but I still feel my particular interest is not on topic for that particular site.

Assuming I can get such a SE site started, how would I go about it? What would be a good way to gauge interest in a SE site like that?

Answer (score 9):

According to the post [On proposals soliciting reviews, recommendations, comparisons, etc](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24050/on-proposals-soliciting-reviews-recommendations-comparisons-etc) by Robert Cartaino, such a proposal would not be accepted.

> proposals have pushed out even further into website recommendations, book recommendations, travel recommendations, idea exchanges, essay reviews, textbook errata, job scams registries, software comparisons, suggest-a-song —
>
> I don't have any regrets with the sites we tried, but hardware and software search is about as far as we can take this format; we don't wish to keep expanding this model any further.

Answer (score 6):

The "review my work" model works for Code Review, but when we tried it on Writing (previously Writers) it did not work, so critique questions are now banned.  Askers had trouble following our rules for critiques, which required that you describe what you're looking for help with instead of just saying "here's my story -- comments?".  Code Review has been able to enforce stronger rules, possibly because the site is *entirely about* reviewing code.  The scope of Writing is broader, and critiques didn't work within it.

It is very, very unlikely that you will be able to get a site for reviewing blog posts, articles, and other written works.  Such a site would be much more a discussion forum than a Q&A site with answers that could be objectively evaluated.  Stack Exchange's focus is Q&A, not discussion.

You might find the answers to [this question about critique sites](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/904/1993) helpful.